# presenting MFMailComposeViewController modally from iPhone addressbook

Tags: iphone

I am building an iPhone app which sends email to contacts from address-book.

After selecting the email-address from a persons contact...i want to use MFMailComposeViewController and present the MailComposeViewController modally, but on tap to email field of contact it launches the mail application....

how can i discard the default functionality of switching to mail app and use  MFMailComposeViewController instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController 
shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
                           property:(ABPropertyID)property 
                         identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue
```

return `NO` and present the MailComposeViewController from there when  `property==kABPersonEmailProperty`.